# Structures preserved by the (co)unit of an adjunction

Tags: category-theory

It is a classical fact that left adjoints preserve colimits (resp. right adjoints preserve limits). Are there any interesting mathematical structures which are preserved by the unit or counit of an adjunction?

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of thing that you're thinking about that might be "preserved" by a natural transformation?

Comment: Sure, I intentionally left this question pretty open-ended. One very specific example that I had in mind is the perspective on natural transformations between two functors $F,G : C\to D$ that they can be thought of as functors $\eta: C\times 2 \to G$, where 2 denotes the arrow category. After applying the classifying space functor $B : \textit{Cat} \to \textit{Top}$, natural transformations become homotopies. So we might think of natural transformations as preserving some homotopy-theoretic structures of the categories and functors, which is witnessed by the classifying space construction.